# using OutOfBoundsException for non arrays

Tags: php, exception, spl

Say I have a method that takes in values between 0 and x. If the parameter is greater than x or less than zero I want to throw an Exception. Is `OutOfBoundsException` a reasonable Exception to throw?

http://php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php says it is an "Exception thrown if a value is not a valid key". Since I'm not using this Exception with arrays (and henceforth keys) is it still okay if I use it?

I mean, on one hand, it seems like it doesn't really matter. Like if I threw a `BadMethodCallException` exception and the person using the method knew that and was either catching for that or for `Exception` it seems that that'd be sufficient, but it'd be nice to have exceptions that make sense too.

Comment: should not be an issue. But I would recommend extending it with your own  more intuitive Exception.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine and appropriate to use for something like this. Exceptions aren't usually tightly-coupled to their original uses. It's "out of bounds" as outside the range of allowed values, so it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

From the predefined SPL exceptions, I would prefer `InvalidArgumentException`. However its documentation says:

> Exception thrown if an argument is not of the expected type.

And the type of the argument is not the problem in your case. Another option is `UnexpectedValueException`

> Exception thrown if a value does not match with a set of values. Typically this happens when a function calls another function and expects the return value to be of a certain type or value not including arithmetic or buffer related errors.

If you ignore the *"typically..."* sentence, this should be suitable.

> I mean, on one hand, it seems like it doesn't really matter. Like if I threw a `BadMethodCallException` exception and the person using the method knew that and was either catching for that or for `Exception` it seems that that'd be sufficient, but it'd be nice to have exceptions that make sense too.

I totally agree on that. And since the predefined exceptions are not *that* clearly documented, I would rather implement my own one. You can still extend `RuntimeException` from SPL.